# verifying code deployed with web3.js

Tags: web3js, solc, verify, bytecode

I am deploying my smart contracts using web3.js and compiling the code using solc. The contracts are deployed successfully with no issues however I am having a bit of a problem in verifying my contract code. Mostly the issue relies in the code flattening process as I am doing it manually and it seems to be generating a different byte code than the one I have compiled and deployed.

Basically here is how I deploy my multi file contract:

```
var inputs = {
        'Main.sol': fs.readFileSync('./Contracts/Main.sol').toString(),
    };

    // Assumes imported files are in the same folder/local path
    function findImports(path) {
        return {
            'contents': fs.readFileSync('./Contracts/' + path).toString()
        }
    }

    var output = solc.compile({sources: inputs}, 0, findImports);
    const bytecode = output.contracts['Main.sol:Main'].bytecode;
    const abi = JSON.parse(output.contracts['Main.sol:Main'].interface);

    const contract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
    let gasLimit = web3.eth.getBlock("latest").gasLimit;

const contractInstance = contract.new({
        data: '0x' + bytecode,
        from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
        gas: gasLimit/2,       
        chainId: 3
    }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        // Log the tx, you can explore status with eth.getTransaction()
        console.log(res.transactionHash);

        // If we have an address property, the contract was deployed
        if (res.address) {
            console.log('Contract address: ' + res.address);
            // Let's test the deployed contract
            testContract(res.address);
        }
    });
```

The code above works and the contract is deployed and is fully functional.

Is there a way to automatically flatten the code and create a single sol file using web3 or any other tool.

EDIT: I tried using [this utility](https://github.com/poanetwork/solidity-flattener) but still etherscan complains that the flattened code's bytcode does not match the contract

Answer (score 0):

For creating a flat file I like [truffle-flattener](https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-flattener).
Just npm install truffle-flattener

Run locally
node node-modules/.bin/truffle-flattener ./contracts/your_contract.sol > contract_flat.sol